# Communication between microservice using messages and REST

Tags: node.js, express, apache-kafka, architecture

I have two Microservices A and B (express and typescript). When B creates and object b referred to an object a from Microservice A, it needs to verify that exists first.

I thought in implementing a local storage, when A create or delete an object publish a message in a queue (Kafka) and subscribers update the cache. Also allows async communication between microservices, for example if one microservice wants to create a resource in another that takes time to be created. However I want to conserve API Rest to expose publicly or when I need a sync communication.

I thought three approaches:

1. Make two services, one a rest api, one consumer of the queue (for example kafka) both working on same domain.
2. Running the api, and in background or async the queue consumer.
3. The microservice just consume messages, create a rest api that receives requests and transform into messages, waiting the response message and returning the response

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing preventing an express app from also running a Kafka consumer. I'm doing it in my own projects (although NestJS has included Kafka support that I'd recommend instead)

But yes, you may want to consider a CQRS and/or Outbox architecture pattern, depending on backend database / storage

For communications between services, you could use gRPC, REST, Kafka or any other message queue...

Comment: Is clean to have also a running Kafka consumer? I don't know any reason why it can't be clean

Comment: What do you mean by "clean"?

Comment: easy to maintain, scalable...

Comment: It can be. What specific issue are you having?

Comment: I think that I cannot scale independently message queue and api, so maybe the approach of having two microservices is better

Comment: You can. See https://keda.sh/